# htaccess from https to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have these vales in my htacces file it all works fine except when i try to go back to http from https i have tried swapping the rules around with no success, any help would be awsome

I have tried all the sujestion with still no suucess so maybe i need to show you guys the entire thing.

Still not going back to http from https, here is the whole thing
Have i got the rules in the wrong order? im lost

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# For Sales:

RewriteRule ^shop/sales/?$ sales.php
# For the primary categories:

RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Z-Aa-z\+]+)/?$ shop.php?type=$1
# For specific products:

RewriteRule ^browse/([A-Za-z\+]+)/([A-Za-z\+\-]+)/([0-9]+)$ browse.php?type=$1&category=$2&id=$3
#For https pages:

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L=301]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://{HTTP_HOST}/$1[R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: This will create an infinite loop if you hadn't an invalid flag in the second rule.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test the rules, but I think you need to change the following:

In the first rule your flag is attached to the 2nd argument. This should create an internal error. Your second rule would rewrite all url's to their http equivalent, making an infinite loop. You need to make sure it doesn't match url's that you want to be in https. You can do this with `%{REQUEST_URI}` and a negation (`!`). As far as I am aware, `L=301` is an invalid flag too. You probably meant to make it `R=301`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(checkout\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$
RewriteRule ^http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Last but not least an word of advice. Don't test your `.htaccess` with permanent redirects until everything works as expected. The browser will cache permanent redirects, not picking up further tries to make your `.htaccess` work as you want.